# What is the Sequence in Drop7?

Tags: drop7

In [Drop7](http://areacodeinc.com/projects/drop7/)'s Sequence mode, what is the full sequence of discs that are dropped? Has this been documented by anyone? I've seen mentions that there definitely is a sequence to the numbers, but not exactly what it is. I'm assuming the person seen in the below video did figure out the sequence if they achieved a score of 5,000,000.

Comment: The entire 7,777 disc sequence can be found here: https://drop7-sequence.github.io/drop7-sequence/ I tried to add as an answer but it got flagged. Not sure commenting an 8 KB text string is appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Here are the first 261 pieces you drop (COMPLETE)

2
1
1
6?
4
5
5?
5?
1?
6
1
5
7
5
3
6
3
2?
6
4?
2
5
7
1
2?
5
1?
3?
2?
4

5
5
2?
1?
6?
2?
3
2
3
2?
3?
6
2
7
7
6
3?
2?
6?
4
7
4
5
4
3
6
1
6?
1

5
7?
4
6
3
5?
7
4
3
5
2
6?
2
7
2
1
4
7
4?
4
2
7
3
5?
5
5
1?
7?

7
7?
2
7?
2
3?
2
3
2?
2
6?
5?
4?
6?
5
7?
2
6
7?
7?
5?
4
2
3?
7
2
3

2?
1
3?
4
1
3?
1?
1
6
1?
5
7
5?
2
5
5
6?
3
5?
4?
5
7
4
1
3?
5

1
6
4
7?
3
7
3
7
7?
4
4?
1
5
1?
5
1
4?
4
3?
4
7
4
3
1
4?
5
5?

7?
5?
5?
1
3
6?
2?
2
3
7
5
4
5
6
1
6
7?
1
1
2?
7
3
7
2

2?
7?
7
4?
6?
5
7
5
7
6?
7
4
6
5
1
6?
3
4
7?
7
5
2
6

1
3
7?
6
4
7
3
7
6?
5
5?
6
2
4
3
3
5?
7
4?
7
1?
5?

4
3?
6
5
7?
1?
7
1
5
6
1
7
4?
6
3
6
1
1
1?
5
6

Question mark signifies not visible.

---

Here are all unknown rows that pop up after each level
6457513
1363344
6457334
2271715
2371541
5236271
3671373
1541633
3731114
2163237
5345453
6166733
6425775
7742511
5133535
4745767
1433523
1513643
---4176
-----6-

Dashes signify one I don't know yet

---

And here are the multiplier values (chain scores) for up to a chain of 30

7
39
109
224
391
617
907
1267
1701
2213
2809
3491
4265
5133
6099
7168
8341
9622
11014
12521
14146
15891
17758
19752
21875
24128
26515
29039
31702
34506

Answer (score 2):

I'll start this by saying that I worked on a port of the game to WP7 (and have my own personal Xbox 360 version) that was never released, so I can't come right out with the information requested.

I feel like I can give a few comments though.

That video you posted shows the sequence, if you wanted to document it, you can get all of the information right from the video, at least to that point. you could try an alternate path if you can analyze where that person made mistakes.

I can also probably say that I originally thought this was just a random number generator seeded with the same seed, but it is actually a defined set of values that are pulled from in a large data table in the app, I suppose so it could be the same cross-platform which wouldn't be the case with different system random number generators. So you could pull the sequence from the executable image if you can get it on a PC and figure out where that data is.

Maybe that's a pointer in the right direction. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a (x) behind a number the piece is not visible.
If there is a question mark, ?, where there is suppose to be a number I don't know witch number is behind the block yet.

The starting row is:
6(x),4(x),5(x),7(x),5(x),1(x),3(x)

**Que:**

Level 1:
2,1,1,6(x),4,5,5(x),5(x),1(x),6,1,5,7,5,3,6,3,2(x),6,4(x),2,5,7,1,2(x),5,1(x),?(x),2(x),4

Level 2:
5,5,2(x),1(x),6(x),?(x),3,2,3,?(x),?(x),6,2,7,7,6,3(x),?(x),4,7,4,5,4,3,6,1,?(x),1

Level 3:
5,?(x),4,6,3,?(x),7,4,3,5,2,6(x),2,7,2,1,4,7,?(x),4,2,7,3,?(x),5,5,?(x),?(x)

Level 4:
7,?(x),2,?(x),2,?(x),2,3,?(x),2,6(x),?(x),?(x),?(x),5,?(x),2,6,?(x),?(x),?(x),4,2,?(x),7,2,3,?(x)

Level 5:
1,?(x),4,1,3(x),1(x),1,6,?(x),5,7,5(x),2,5,5,?(x),3,?(x),?(x),5,7,4,1,?(x),5,

Level 6:
1,6,4,7(x),3,7,3,7,7(x),4,?(x),1,5,?(x),5,1,?(x),4,3(x),4,7,4,3,1,?(x)

Level 7:
5,?(x),?(x),?(x),5(x),1,3,?(x),?(x),2,3,7,5,4,5,6,1,6,7(x),1,1,?(x),7,3

Level 8:
7,2,?(x),?(x),7,?(x),6(x),5,7,5,7,?(x),7,4,6,5,1,?(x),3,4,?(x),7,5

Level 9:
2,6,1,3,7(x),6,4,7,3,7,?(x),5,?(x),6,2,4,3,3,?(x),7,?(x),7

Level 10:
?(x),?(x),4,?(x),6,5,1(x),?(x),7,1,5,6,1,7,?(x),6,3,6,1,1,?(x),5

Level 11:
6,4,7,7,4,?(x),?(x),?(x),?(x),4(x),4(x),?(x),?(x),4,?(x),3,?(x),1,?(x)

Level 12:
7,2,7,?(x),?(x),6,?(x),2(x),4,6,2,2,5,5,7,1,7,?(x),3,7

Level 13:

Comment or message me if you have additional information or find that some of the information is incorrect.

I got this information from Android (My Galaxy Nexus ICS). I quess it is the same on the different platforms if not then we need to seperate the thread.

Answer (score -4):

I figured out the discs in sequence mode for the first 71 levels:

[image: sequence]

More information about the project on my blog:
http://programmablebrick.blogspot.com/2013/03/drop7-with-lego-mindstorms-nxt.html

Comment: Please add the sequences to your answer; a link on it's own isn't an answer.

Comment: There are 1035 discs for the first 71 levels and I already stuck them in a table on the page I linked to.

Comment: @user1106281 What if the content gets moved or removed? An answer that consists mostly of a link isn't very helpful to read, an answer that consists mostly of a **dead** link even less so.

Comment: This is really interesting work. Thank you for taking the time to post about it.